# Website Homepage Pop up Image Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently trying to copy the pop up image of www.cancerletter.com to the http://cancer2.live.subhub.com/. I do not know what is exactly missing why it is not working and it is just showing in the bottom of the footer in the website cancer2.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well without seen any of your code, one possible mistake i can think is that you have your pop up static. In that case you need to add position: fixed; to your css.